# Firebase: Retrieve recent email list from iOS on Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Is there a way to retrieve list of recent email account on the Firebase for iOS and Android?

Is it the right thing to get the UID/email and store it to my Realtime database node? Any thoughts that would be helpful to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide some more information, what do you mean by "recently authenticated"? Recently signed up for your app? Or recently logged in?

Comment: recently signup/new user

Answer (score 0):

I know you can view and export your list of users from the Firebase dashboard on the Auth section (after export you can sort by join date using Excel).

If you wish to do it via code, I suggest storing the email and timestamp when I user signs up for your app. Then query the node with all the emails and order by timestamp.